# When you use document.getElementsByTagName() in javascript do you get an array of all the elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` to get all the `<input>` elements on the page. will this result in an array that I can put a for loop through?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `for` loop, but it's not an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that's returned, it's a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList), for example:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
  //do something with inputs[i]
}
```

Comment: @chromedude - yup, you sure can, it's 0-based so `1` would be the 2nd `<input>` element in the page.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not an array, it is an <del>[HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection)</del> NodeList. But the **behave** like arrays so you can use a normal `for` loop to traverse it.

The catch here is that the collection is **live** which means some methods/attributes will make the collection to update (meaning evaluate) again. One of these is `length`, so for performance reasons, you should retrieve this value **once**, e.g.:

```
for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    // so something with elements[i]
}
```

Comment: It's not an HTMLCollection, as you can't do `document.getElementsByTagName('input')["inputName"]`.  HTMLCollection is an interface which NodeList doesn't implement.